# Validar 2 Mask en un mismo Input JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Me dirijo a ustedes porque intento mediante JQuery Hacer una validación en la que involucra validar 2 máscaras en un mismo input.

Quiero validar que, al momento que el usuario ingrese valores, el sistema reconozca los caracteres y, dependiendo de la cantidad de caracteres, actualizar el input con la máscara correspondiente

Un ejemplo seria el siguiente

```
$('#DU').on('blur', function() {

    if($(this).val().length <= 10) {

        $(this).mask('99999999-9');

    }else{

        $(this).mask('9999-999999-999-9');

    } 

});
```

Espero su ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿No se aplica la máscara o solo lo hace bajo ciertas condiciones?

Comment: Buenas noches, el problema es que no aplica la mascara, logre que aplicara una mascara pero no aplica ambas.

Comment: El "problema" es que al aplicar la máscara, hace los cambios al modificar el campo. Tal vez puedas intentar [cambiarla al teclear](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#on-the-fly-mask-changes)